# How to Share Link on Facebook using FBSDKShareLink?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook"];
NSURL *imageURL =
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Facebook_Headquarters_Menlo_Park.jpg/2880px-Facebook_Headquarters_Menlo_Park.jpg"];

content.contentDescription=@"This is facebook test";
content.contentTitle=@"Hello";
content.imageURL=imageURL;


FBSDKShareButton *shareButton = [[FBSDKShareButton alloc] init];
shareButton.shareContent = content;
shareButton.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:shareButton];
```

I used facebook-ios-sdk-3.24.0.pkg and  I am using the above code for link sharing on facebook using fbsdksharekit. This code is working fine but after closing the xcode and reopen that xcode6.0 it shows the below error.
`FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h` and `FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h` not found.

i import those frameworks i.e `FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h` and `FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h` to `viewcontroller.m` file .

can any one tell me what is the problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: facebook-ios-sdk-3.24.0.pkg is it latest sdk?

Comment: This is download link for SDK 4.6 Version https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910.zip

Comment: First of all thanks for reply. FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910 i.e 4.6.In this sdk when i ran application it showed following error:146 duplicate symbols for architecture i386

Comment: You have added library for multiple time

Comment: thanks its working fine..  i will keep in touch with u

Comment: but it is working fine for first time but after quit the xcode and reopen that xcode6.0 it shows the below error. FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h and FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h not found

Comment: is there Framework search paths problem? because FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h and FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Below Code to Share on Facebook, download latest [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios)

```
    FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
    content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook"];
    NSURL *imageURL =
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Facebook_Headquarters_Menlo_Park.jpg/2880px-Facebook_Headquarters_Menlo_Park.jpg"];
    content.contentDescription=@"This is facebook test";
    content.contentTitle=@"Hello";
    content.imageURL=imageURL;
    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:nil];
```

Comment: thanks for reply,how to share images and videos on fb using fbsdk sharelink

Comment: can you give me example

Comment: You Download Facebook SDK, Inside SDK have Example in it.

Comment: FacebookSDK > Sample > Shareit .. example are also there.